# Only the graph axis shows up when I try to plot CSV data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a CSV file with zip codes and a corresponding number for each zip code.  I want to plot it using a histogram, but right now only the axis are showing up, with none of the actual information.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

installedbase = 'zipcode.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(installedbase)

df.plot(x = 'zip_code_installed', y = 'installed_NP', kind = 'hist', rwidth = .5, bins = 1000 )
plt.xlabel('zip code')
plt.ylabel('NP sum')
plt.axis([9000,9650,0,6400])

plt.show()
```

I am using pandas and matplotlib to plot.  "x" and "y" are both set to different columns in my CSV file.

Comment: Have you checked df to make sure that it has those column names?

Comment: hist does only support 1D Histograms, what do you wnat to achieve with passing x and y?

Comment: The column names are in the CSV file verbatim.  I was not aware hist could only take one set of data.  What would allow me to plot both sets against each other?